# CSS: Changing Span color on mouseover

Tags: css

How should I go about changing the color of a span on mouseover? I currently have a tab (like in a menu) that has been classified as a span, let's say .rtsOut with a background color of #595959. Each tab is still classified as the same span, .rtsOut, but is divided into 4 different tabs. When I mouseover, I'd like to change that one tab to to, #000000, and to revert back to #595959 when the mouse is moved off of the span.

I unfortunately don't have access to the whole overlook of CSS like so:

```
<style>
span:hover {
  background: ######;
}
</style>
```

and instead I have a very simple view like this, where I just input single lines of code:

```
#SampleThing {visibility: hidden;}
```

Can anyone help me? I've been Googling, and testing for hours, and can't come up with a solution.

So far, this is what I've found. I believe this is how the span has been created:

```
 <li class="rtsLI"> == $0
      <a class="rtsLink tbLeft4" id="TbInformation" href="../Info/Info.aspx">
           <span class="rtsOut">
                <span class="rtsIn">
                     <span class="rtsTxt">Edit Information</span>
                </span>
           </span>
      </a>
 </li>
```

And I've tried changing the background color of that span using this:

```
 .rtsOut:hover {background: #000000;}
```

However, that line of code isn't working :(

Comment: Should be on the right track, try adding `.rtsOut:hover` vs `span:hover`

Comment: Please could you add your ("*[mcve]*") HTML to your question?

Comment: Have you tried `developer tools` in your browser of choice to attempt the change? Also attrempt the change on classes `rtsIn` and `rtsText`. One more thing... is the missing `=` and `" "` missing from the markup your error or what you see?

Comment: I haven't tried using developer tools, no. Sorry, I'm not adept at coding.

Comment: your html is wrong on the second span check my answer.

Comment: On a Windows PC hit `F12` while in your browser. On a Mac hit `CMD + Option + i`. This will open developer tools and allow you to see HTML, CSS and JS among other things. You can change, edit or add HTML and CSS as well (Also run scripts) through here, seeing changes dynamically.

Comment: try sticking an !important to your CSS rule to see if there are any CSS specificity issues that prevent this from working.

like so: .rtsOut:hover { background: #000000 !important; }

Comment: Dang, that looked like it would work, but it's not working :(

Answer (score 0):

> When I mouseover, I'd like to change that one tab to to, #000000, and
>   to revert back to #595959 when the mouse is moved off of the span.

```css
 .rtsOut:hover {background: #000000;}
```

```html
 <span class="rtsOut">
      <span class="rtsIn">
           <span class="rtsTxt">Edit Information</span>
      </span>
 </span>
```

Comment: Sorry Roberto, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be looking at here :x It looks like you just copy and pasted the exact same code that I posted in my question.

Comment: No, it is not. Look more carefully. This is your `<span class "rtsIn">`. That's wrong, the equal is missing and that's why it isn't working.

Comment: Roberto, good catch! The = is there, I just typed it wrong in here. I've updated my original post with the =.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my [codePen here](http://codepen.io/illdapt/pen/WGGaOq)

CSS

```
.rtsOut:hover{
    background-color: red;  
}
```

HTML (Assuming it looks like this)

```
<div>
    <p>
        <span class="rtsOut">One</span>
        <span class="rtsOut">Two</span>
        <span class="rtsOut">Three</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Also note that if you would like some more flexibility down the road, you may want to look into using `<ul>` and `<li>` for Nav Menu items.

Comment: I think that my HTML code (I didn't know that HTML was the whole thing and CSS was just lines, so thank you! Now I know!), is set up just the way you have it here, but the CSS code that you listed isn't working.

Comment: You may have something not allowing the change i.e. another `:hover`. Try `.rtsOut:hover{background-color: red !important;}`

Comment: Is there a live source to view this? Do you have a JSFiddle or CodePen to look at? I would love to help degbug but without CSS and a full page markup it is difficult.

Comment: There is, but I'm a bit leery about posting the code here. It's for a website that a company made that I can alter using CSS. I don't have access to the whole HTML side of things. Is there any way we can go into the stackexchange chat so I can show you the code? (If I can ever figure out how to use the chat). Nevermind. Need 20 reputation :(

Comment: Curious, what platform is it on (Specifically how are you adding the CSS)?

Comment: The website has a Layout Manager where I go and input lines of CSS code.

Comment: Okay! Update! So what the tabs look like is this: On the outside is .rtsOut. Then inside of it is .rtsIn (but .rtsOut is wider, so .rtsIn fits inside) and then we have .rtxTxt. So when I did the .rtsOut hover, it doesn't work. But when I do .rtsIn, it works! The color changes, but because .rtsIn isn't has large, it looks funny since the entire tab doesn't change color if that makes sense. So the code works...just not for .rtsOut or something? :( Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Ah ok try a CSS line like this `.rtsOut:hover .rtsTxt {  color: red; }` or `.rtsIn:hover .rtsTxt {  color: red; }`

Comment: Not working :( I updated my original post with what I think is a fuller code. I also tried this .rtsOut .rtsIn .rstTxt:hover {background-color: red;} and it still didn't work.

Comment: Seeing as there is an `<li>` also try `.rtsLI:hover .rtsTxt { color: red !important; }'

Comment: I updated PEN above to reflect new changes with `<li>`

Comment: Hey, I tried those, and they're not working. When I do this though .rtsIn:hover .rtsTxt { color: red !important} the color of the text changes, but nothing else.

Comment: What do you want to change color? if is the background instead of `color: red` it would be `background-color: red`

Comment: Yes, it's the background color. So, imagine we have a big box (rtsOut). And inside that big box is a small box (rtsIn). Now the small box has the same height, but isn't as wide, so we shift rtsIn to the right. So now there's a gap on the left between the edge of rtsOut and rtsIn. The code that you've given me works so very beautifully! But that gap doesn't change color :(

Comment: Target the 'TOP' container. In your case it should be the `<li>` with a class of `rtsLI` only  `.rtsLI:hover{Your CSS}`. If that is too much and your looking for a smaller scope target the next TOP. `.rtsLI:hover .rtsOUT{Your CSS}`... Then So on. Also the closing `>` for the first `<a>` is missing Could be an issue.

Comment: I tried both, not working :( I'm really puzzled as to why. .rtsOut just REFUSES to change color.

Comment: For me is wasn't as well... until I fixed the `>` after address. `href="../Info/Info.aspx">` <---HERE ___ If you go to pen and remove that `>` notice the `:hover` breaks. Wonder if that is an issue on your version?

Comment: Haha, sorry! I'm retarded and just didn't type that in correctly. There is a > at the end of that already.

Comment: Is there a way to just increase the width of a span using CSS? Then I can just extend .rtsIn to match the size of .rtsOut maybe? Edit: Wait no, that wouldn't work because each tab is a different width....

Comment: You could use the attribute `width: 100%` which should fill the Parent Container fully with the Child Container. This would also allow for altering size of Parents, in your case tabs.

Comment: Er, could you tell me how to implement width: 100% in the css code exactly? Sorry, I'm a newbie. I tried .rtsIn {width: 100% !important} but it's not working

Comment: I tried this as well `.rtsIn{width:100%; display:inline-block; !important}
.rtsIn:hover{background-color: #97885e !important}` and it's not working.The color changes for .rtsIn, but since it's not the same size as .rtsOut, it's not filling the entire space.

Comment: Take a look at the updated PEN. You will need to include `display: inline-block;` to the CSS of the `<span>` element you want to adjust. This is because non-block elements cannot have widths/heights applied.

Comment: Aslo, note in the updated I have two `:hover`, one for the `.rtsLI` and one for `.rtsOut`, allowing both to change for your hover event.

Comment: *sigh* Sorry, I'm not sure if I'm just doing this wrong or something, but it's not working :( Would you be okay to teamviewer or something so you can see exactly what I'm looking at?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your HTML really is:

```
 <span class="rtsOut">
      <span class="rtsIn">
           <span class="rtsTxt">Edit Information</span>
      </span>
 </span>
```

and this isn't working:

```
 .rtsOut:hover {background: #000000;}
```

Then, it tells me that someone has generated styles that are "more specific" than the ones you are providing.

CSS styling rules are applied from "most specific to least specific". For example: `parent > .rtsOut { background-color: red; }` will take precedence over `.rtsOut { background-color: blue; }` because it is more specific. As well, inline styles will have one of the highest precedence, so `<span class="rtsOut" style="background-color:red;"></span>` will override `.rtsOut { background-color: blue; }`. See http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/ for more information.

I would start by adding `!important` to your styles (as this will always have the highest precedence if nothing else has been given `!important`), to see if the above is the case.

Also, I would most definitely get used to browser developer tools. They allow you to delve right into the active code and do live edits. You will be able to see if there is an inline style or another style rule that has more precedence over the one you are trying to provide.

Comment: Heather, that makes a lot of sense. I did add the !important to my line like so: .rtsOut:hover { background: #000000 !important; }, but it's still not working. As far as the developer tools go, I would have no idea where to add that line for the hover color change in that giant wall of code in order to actually get the hover working.

Comment: @lolikols It depends on the browser; for example, in Chrome right click the `span` and press "Inspect". Go to the "Elements" tab and click `<span class="rtsOut>` in the HTML view; you should now see the CSS view for that `span`. First, check for inline styles in the HTML view. Second, check for any rules with `!important` in CSS view. Third, under the rule `element.styles {}`, try adding a background color (this is the inline styles rule, should have highest precedence). Finally, there is a plus(+) in the CSS viewer (top-right corner) for adding new rules. Add `.rtsOut:hover` and the bg color.